# Create arrays with cycles

Tags: php, arrays, variables, cycle

I have the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++) 
{
    $goods_{$i} = array(
        $_POST["'goods'.$i'_title'"],
        $_POST["'goods'.$i.'_package'"],
        $_POST["'goods'.$i.'_nmr'"]
    );
}
```

I hoped that it could make this in first step of the cycle:

```
$i =1;
$goods_1 = array(
    $_POST['goods1_title'], 
    $_POST['goods1_package'], 
    $_POST['goods1_nmr']
);
```

and so on in other steps.

Comment: Just get rid of the single quotes and dots in the double-quoted strings: `$_POST["goods{$i}_title"]`

Comment: @jeroen This didn't help. Somewhere is syntax mistake, because the white screen still appears.

Comment: Then [enable error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) and find out where the syntax error occurs.

Comment: Why in the world are you doing this? You are using arrays, keep using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow AbraCadaver's sentiments:

> *Why* in the world are you doing this? You are using arrays, keep using them.

As such, I would write the code simply using an [Array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$goods = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++) 
{
    // Assign to an index in the already created array,
    // but DO NOT create a new variable.
    $goods[$i] = array(
        // Also make sure these are correct ..
        $_POST["goods{$i}_title"],
    );
}
```

If you *really* want to create dynamic variables - ick! - see [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: @nicael Your answer discussed the secondary string building which I address in passing. I believe the primary issue is the `$goods_$i` syntax/goal.

Comment: "As such, I would write the code simply as:" - you can write it even more simple ... :) Just define array as `$goods = []`.

Comment: @JakubPolák Old/familiar habits die hard - that would work, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++) 
{
    ${"goods_$i"} = array(
        $_POST["'goods'.$i'_title'"],
        $_POST["'goods'.$i.'_package'"],
        $_POST["'goods'.$i.'_nmr'"]
    );
}
```

You can read more about this topic in [related PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

The result of `"'goods'.$i'_title'"` will be `'goods'.1'_title'`, in case that you want it to be `goods1_title` then use following code instead:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++) 
{
    ${"goods_$i"} = array(
        $_POST["goods{$i}_title"],
        $_POST["goods{$i}_package"],
        $_POST["goods{$i}_nmr"]
    );
}
```

Another bug might be that in 1 case you use `.$i.` and in other 2 cases you use `.$i` without the last `.`.

Comment: @user2864740 Probably not, but the prime problem is in definition variable of variable.

Comment: If you are going to use variable-variables (ick!), consider the form `${'goods_' . $i} = array(..)`.

Comment: @user2864740 I agree, that is even better approach.

Comment: Ah, yes. Shows how much I use variable variables :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
    $_POST["goods{$i}_title"],
    $_POST["goods{$i}_package"],
    $_POST["goods{$i}_nmr"]
```

Comment: @DanyCaissy Why are you saying lies? I can't down vote. It requires 125 reputation.

Comment: Problem is that creating variable of variable does not work this way `$goods_{$i}`. That is probably why your answer was downvoted.

Comment: Try to build the variable that way and after that use `var_dump($goods_1)`, you will get `NULL`.

Comment: please add some explanation of your code, and explain what the OP was doing wrong